# Pygame collision, didnt use pygame.sprite

Tags: python, collision

So im making a little game where you can walk around a town and i already have most of my walking animations complete and some music and all that. now i need to add collisions. i drew a rectangle over the area that i want collision to occur but i dont know what to do from here. (The rect atributes are towards the bottom of the code) i want my player to stop walking when he hits the rect that i drew

```
import pygame
import pyganim
import time
import pygame.gfxdraw
pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
y = 200
x = 300
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
pygame.mixer.music.load("gamesong.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
global playerAnim
#imports pygame and initializes the module
pygameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((958,910))
bg = pygame.image.load("map.png")
#creates a screen
pygame.display.set_caption("pokemon-ish")
gameExit = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("left walk 0.png",.3)])
while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -10
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("left walk 1.png",0.3),("left walk 2.png", 0.3),("left walk 3.png",0.3),("left walk 4.png",0.3)])
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = +10
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("walk right 1.png",0.3),("walk right 2.png", 0.3),("walk right 3.png",0.3),("walk right 4.png",0.3)])
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -10
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("walk right 1.png",0.3),("walk right 2.png", 0.3),("walk right 3.png",0.3),("walk right 4.png",0.3)])
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("walk forward 1.png", 0.3)])

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = +10
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("walk down 1.bmp", 0.3),("walk down 2.bmp", 0.3)])

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = 0
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("left walk 2.png",.3)])
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
                playerAnimLeft = pyganim.PygAnimation([("walk right 2.png",.3)])
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0



    pygame.draw.rect(pygameDisplay,(0),[192,145,187,182]) 
    pygameDisplay.blit(bg,(0,0))
    playerAnimLeft.blit(pygameDisplay, (x,y))
    playerAnimLeft.play()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You should show some codes that you tried, we are not code workers. There is bunch of codes here how you expect we can help you, minimize it please.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your object to `pygame.Rect` object, then use some methods like `pygame.rect.colliderect` for to catch if your object collide with another one. It's not possible to write an answer since you just wrote your whole code, you should watch some pygame tutorials about collisions. Check [**here**](http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html).

> It's just a simple example how to use `colliderect`;

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

x=0
y=0

rect2= pygame.Rect (500,30,50,20) #we should make a rect object first

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
running=True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 10
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 10

    gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))

    rect1= pygame.Rect (x,y,100,200) #big rect object
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255,255,255) , rect1) #drawing them
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255,255,255) , rect2)

    if rect1.colliderect(rect2):          #if first one which is 
        rect2= pygame.Rect (50,500,50,20) #we are controlling it with arrow keys
                                          #collide with other one
    pygame.display.update()               #change the coordinates of that rectangle

    clock.tick()
```

Move the big rectangle with arrow keys, if you touch the small rectangle, it will move to the left of the screen

Comment: I'm going to add an example for you wait a sec please